# Polling for properties returns unexpected json

Tags: autodesk-model-derivative

When polling for properties after the translation of a model we get unexpected JSON. Here it is:

[image]

What could be the reason here?

Comment: Do we need to provide more info? What would that info be?

Comment: Please, provide the code and the corresponding result as text.

Comment: What exactly is the unexpected part in this mess? What did you expect instead? Does it always happen? Only for certain URLs? Any changes just before this started to happen?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Thomas thank you for your question.
Basically it can happened because getting metadata is not complete, did you get manifest before getting geometry data?

> https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/

Also can you tell original file format? It can be also a reason, in this case I will check it with dev. team

Comment: Hi @K_2
- I attached the log in text format (request and result)
- We experienced it with .nwd file format
- We get the manifest, it goes wrong after a while when we are polling for properties

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cBJAWp0pulXsJtGDPwJr3R7QjepUakM9

Comment: Thomas thank you for answer, I will contact with dev. team and return to you asap.

Comment: For now I have small update from dev team. and as I thought from the beginning they ask me to ask you - can you share this sample which is give you such result )))